# Save jupyter notebook results(dataframe as picture or pdf)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The problem is like this: I use a tool 'alphalens' to generate some result like below:

[image]

I'd like to save the output as picture or pdf , is there any method to do this?
I want to save the result by writing code becouse there are many reusults to save.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to, (and it's not ideal), then you could do something like starting a matplotlib.pyplot frame and using the built in imsave method like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print "Creates a plot or chart like the one above"
plt.imsave("Path/To/Save", plotname)
```

the documentation is [Here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=im%20save#matplotlib.pyplot.imsave).
Be sure the data is saveable too